# Problemas com sessão PHP - Continuar uma sessão

Tags: php, session

Estou montando o site de uma cliente e preciso fazer o controle de login. 
O usuário consegue se logar normalmente e sem erro, mas ao mandá-lo para a página principal quando ele está logado é como se não tivesse iniciado a sessão.
Aqui está meu código:

> login.php

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="conf/logar.php" method="POST">
    <fieldset>
        <!-- Text input-->
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="user">Usuario</label>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <input id="user" name="user" placeholder="login" class="form-control input-md" required="" type="text">
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Password input-->
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="senha">Senha</label>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <input id="senha" name="senha" placeholder="senha" class="form-control input-md" required="" type="password">
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Button -->
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="log">Login</label>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <button id="log" name="log" class="btn btn-success">Login</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

> logar.php

```
include("conexao.php");

$user = $_POST["user"];
$senha = $_POST["senha"];

$userBusca = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE usuario_login = '".$user.
    "' AND usuario_senha = '".$senha.
    "' ") or die(mysql_error("Erro ao fazer login"));

if (mysql_num_rows($userBusca) == 1) {
    session_start(); //Inicia a sessão
    $_SESSION["usuario_nome"] = $_POS["user"];
    $_SESSION["usuario_senha"] = $_POST["senha"];
    header("Location:../index_logado.php");

} else {
    "<script>
    alert('Usuário não encontrado! Informe os dados corretamente');
    window.location.href = '../login.php'; < /script>";
}
```

Criei uma página que controla se o usuário está com a sessão iniciada ou não.

> restrito.php

```
@session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION["usuario_nome"])){

}else{
    header("Location:login.php");
}
```

Mas ao incluir 'restrito.php' na 'index_logado.php' é como se o usuário naõ tivesse se logado e não consigo resgatar os dados da sessão.
Agradeço pela ajuda. Vlws!

Comment: Você aplictou `session_start();` em todos documentos?

Comment: Quero alertá-lo que passar dados diretamente na query é dar entrada para sql injection. Além disso, mysql_query está sendo descontinuado, sugiro vc utilizar PDO ou mysqi.

Comment: A sessão do tipo de método `$_SESSION` só pode ser resgatada em outra página, quando definida no cabeçalho do arquivo `session_start()`, nunca na mesma página onde você setou a sessão. Talvez seja esse o seu problema.

Comment: Não, coloquei >session_start(); somente na hora em que ele vai logar e depois quando ele verifica dentro do >restrito.php. Acredito que dando um include ele pega a session.
E em relação ao resto estou ciente disso. Vou utilizar modos de evitar sql injection, mas do que me adianta se estou com este empecilho? Não consegui conectar com mysqli e não sei utilizar e nem o que é PDO. Mas agradeço pelo comentário.

Comment: mysqli: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.mysqli.php e PDO: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.pdo.php

Comment: Obrigado pelos manuais! =]

Comment: asordi ----------------------------- =)

Answer (score 1):

Cara, tenho fortes expectativas de ter achado seu problema:

Você adicionou o nome do usuário na sessão assim:
 $_SESSION["usuario_nome"] = **$_POS**["user"];

Está faltando um T;
Sendo assim $_SESSION["usuario_nome"] retorna NULL;

Answer (score 0):

Há uma arroba antes do `session_start()`, vou me arriscar a dizer que ela está lá porque chegou a gerar `warnings` ou alguma outra saída indesejada. Se foi isto, a saída indesejada não foi a toa, indica uma situação que merece atenção.

Se o `session_start()` indica que os cabeçalhos já foram enviados, obviamente haverão problemas na execução do PHP e a arroba vai evitar somente que o alerta para os possíveis problemas sejam exibidos, mas eles vão ocorrer tento alertas ou não.

`session_start()` deve ser chamado antes de qualquer saída do servidor para o navegador, se tiver alguma dúvida, melhor colocar no início da execução do código.

Como primeira medida recomendo tirar a arroba e ver o que aparece. Se estiver normal, tire o redirecionamento da página que autentica (`logar.php`) e veja se há saída. Pelo que vi, não pode haver saída. Lembrar que o navegador deve ter cookies habilitados ou então a url deve conter algo parecido com `PHPSESSION=xxxxxxxx`.

Avisos, alertas e erros não são ruins, normalmente ruim é ignorá-los. Isto só se refere à arroba, com ela nem se sabe se há algum problema.

Comment: Oi cara. Não era isso não, eu já consegui resolver. Era só um "T" depois do $_POST que estava faltando, mas ainda assim obrigado pelo comentário.

Comment: então marque a resposta do @Renan como resolvido.

Comment: @DanielOmine Provavelmente não foi marcada como resolvida porque este comentário da solução foi feito uns 20 dias antes da resposta do Renan.